# Adding CSS to Jquery knob?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-knob, round-slider

I have 2 questions. Firstly, how do you go about changing the CSS for a knob? I've tried adding a class to it but that didn't seem to work. Neither did doing inline styling. Anyone have any clue how this can be done (An example would be amazing)?

Secondly, does anyone have any idea how to modify the size of the knob based on window size? I can't seem to figure out how to make it take percentage inputs.

EDIT: To change the CSS, you must use the Draw function since it is done using Canvas, there is no way to apply CSS to it directly.

This worked for me:

```
$(".dial").knob({
    'draw': function() {
        $(this.i).css('font-size', '100px');
      }
});
```

Comment: are you referring to http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/?

Comment: Yes. Is it not called jquery-Knob? Does it have any other names? (I just started using it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since jQuery Knob using the Canvas, so we can't directly customize this through CSS.

Alternatively you can use the jQuery [**roundSlider**](http://roundsliderui.com/) plugin which is similar to knob, but it constructs based on the div elements only. So you can customize the overall control as per your wish.

For more details check the [demos](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html) and [documentation](http://roundsliderui.com/document.html) page.

Check here the [different appearances](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html#different-theming-and-appearances).

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1:**

To change the color you can use `data-fgColor="#222222"` attribute while initializing the object. As its a canvas CSS won't  work over there. What other style you want to apply?

**Answer 2:**

Update you soon on this.